# Retrieve accounts that don't have any open opportunities

Tags: soql

I want to write a query to retrieve accounts that don't have any open opportunities.

I was looking at nested queries, so I wanted to run something like this:

```
Select id from Account WHERE id  = (SELECT AccountId from Opportunity where IsClosed = false)
```

Comment: Are you receiving any error during query execution..then please mention that also in your question. It will help community users to understand the issue in your side.

Comment: @MohanRaj tells me unknown Error Parsing Query

Comment: Hi, welcome to SFSE. Please take a [tour] and read [ask]. I'd be great if you could edit your question and share more details about your problem, like a bigger piece of code and the exact error message you receive. Also, if you struggle with basic Apex code, I'd recommend you an [Apex Basics & Database](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_database) Trailhead module. Cheers!

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 4):

You need to write a query with `IN` for receiving `account id` list from your nested query `SELECT AccountId from Opportunity where IsClosed = false`.

So your query will be followingly,

`SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId from Opportunity WHERE IsClosed = false)`

And refer this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql.htm) to learn more about SOQL queries.

Answer (score 2):

You may want NOT IN in this case; this will find any accounts with no open opportunities (including those with no opportunities at all):

```
Select id from Account WHERE Id NOT IN (
  SELECT AccountId from Opportunity where IsClosed = true
)
```